# NSDate returning date string

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, nsdate

[NSDate date] is returning time that is 2 min ahead of the actual GMT time in India. Is this a known issue with iPhone SDK?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`[NSDate date]` returns whatever your system's clock is set to. If your system is ahead of the reference clock, then that's what you'll get.

Comment: +1: Why do people think there's a bug in SDK before checking any place else.

Comment: Why is it that the shortest, easiest answers get the most upvotes?